# Is a question about the possibility of an iPad virus on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask, "is it possible for an iPad (or other iOS product) to get a virus?" but I'm not sure this is on topic. Is it?

Btw, I'm pretty sure that it (getting a virus) is not possible (having googled it) but I trust this forum more!

Comment: For completeness, here is the question on the other forum: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18128/is-it-possible-for-an-ipad-or-any-ios-product-to-get-a-virus

Comment: Just to answer your question, it is possible to get a virus if someone used an exploit similar to the recently patched pdf exploit. But it is not very probable, becuase virus makers like to target the largest audience witch is still windows pc users. Apple has also been fairly good about patching security bugs before viruses appear.

Comment: @Joel, thanks. You might want to follow the link I added above and read / post there, just to keep this Q&A clean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This would not be on topic here on Super User, as explained [in the FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq#questions):

> and it is not about...
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - **electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones,
>     except insofar as they interface with your computer**
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Your question would however be on-topic for our sister site, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). which is a Stack Exchange site for Apple products.

Thanks for asking ahead of time to make sure your question fits!

Answer (score 6):

Like nhinkle mentioned, it would be off topic according to the rules of Super User.  The other problem with that kind of question is you are asking for a possibility of a virus on [Enter Desired Platform].  A virus or malware is technically possible on any platform in some degree.  It is more difficult to distribute and install on many platforms, but there is always a chance someone could take advantage of a security hole or some flaw for ill purposes.  It would be difficult to get one, but its not impossible.

And thank you very much for asking on meta before asking the question.  This is a great example of using the meta sites properly for clarified information about Super User.